# How to embed Tkinter window to another one by ID (like Plug in pyGTK does)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I know how to embed another window into a Tkinter's by its ID (for example, show a pygame window or a VLC player instance inside a Tkinter Frame). But is there a way to do vice versa? In pyGTK, there is the `Plug` which does what I need. Maybe, there is something like this in Tkinter, too?